# Resize image, blur image and overlay image

Tags: python, image

This code has the function of removing worthless borders from the original image and then:

1. Generate a 1080x1080 image (Instagram default) to be used as a
   blurred background.
2. Generate an image with a width of 1080 and the height adjusted
   accordingly to maintain the correct aspect ratio.
3. Superimpose `2.` on the blurred background (`1.`)

I would like a review of the quality of the methods I used to reach the final result.

Original image example:

[image]

Code to Review:

```
from PIL import Image, ImageFilter, ImageChops
import numpy
import cv2

def remove_border(file_img):
    im = Image.open(file_img)
    bg = Image.new("RGB", im.size, im.getpixel((0,0)))
    diff = ImageChops.difference(im.convert("RGB"), bg)
    diff = ImageChops.add(diff, diff, 2.0, -30)
    bbox = diff.getbbox()
    if bbox:
        return im.crop(bbox)

def resize_blur(img_blur,sizers):
    img_blur = img_blur.resize(sizers, resample=Image.Resampling.LANCZOS)
    img_blur = img_blur.filter(ImageFilter.GaussianBlur(10))
    return img_blur

def resize_width_main(img_border,size_width):
    img_width = img_border
    basewidth = size_width
    wpercent = (basewidth/float(img_width.size[0]))
    hsize = int((float(img_width.size[1])*float(wpercent)))
    img_width = img_width.resize((basewidth,hsize), Image.Resampling.LANCZOS)
    return img_width

def center_overlay(name_file,overlay,background):
    img = numpy.asarray(overlay)
    img = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_RGB2BGR)
    h, w = img.shape[:2]
    back = numpy.asarray(background)
    back = cv2.cvtColor(back, cv2.COLOR_RGB2BGR)
    hh, ww = back.shape[:2]
    yoff = round((hh-h)/2)
    xoff = round((ww-w)/2)
    result = back.copy()
    result[yoff:yoff+h, xoff:xoff+w] = img
    cv2.imwrite(name_file, result)

def main():
    img_border = remove_border('resized_download.png')
    img_blur = resize_blur(img_border, (1080,1080))
    img_width = resize_width_main(img_border, 1080)
    center_overlay('resized.png', img_width, img_blur)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Final image example:

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After upgrading to Pillow 9.1.1: I still think your imports could use some love, because there's ambiguity between `Image` the submodule and `Image` the class. (PIL chose poorly when naming the submodule.)

By convention Numpy is imported by `import numpy as np`. However, I am going to suggest that you not drop down to Numpy or `cv` at all: instead stay in Pillow and use `.paste()`.

Add PEP484 type hints.

I suggest that you decouple your processing methods from file I/O so that they only operate on in-memory images and arrays.

This:

```
if bbox:
    return im.crop(bbox)
```

implicitly returns `None` if the condition is not met, but your upper code is not written to handle that. Either just drop the `if` and bear the consequences, or check if `bbox` is `None` and `raise`.

It's important for many of your function calls such as `add()` that you pass arguments by name, particularly for bare-literal numbers such as `scale=2, offset=-30`.

`img_width = img_border` is confusing. First of all it's an unneeded alias, and second of all it isn't a width: it's an image ("wide image", not "image width"). I would just remove this and use the original variable.

Float promotion is automatic, so this:

```
int((float(img_width.size[1])*float(wpercent)))
```

doesn't need the `float()` casts. You would benefit from tuple-unpacking the size here similar to what you do elsewhere.

### Suggested

```py
from PIL import ImageChops, ImageFilter
from PIL.Image import Image, Resampling
import PIL.Image


def remove_border(image: Image) -> Image:
    bg = PIL.Image.new(mode="RGB", size=image.size, color=image.getpixel((0, 0)))
    diff = ImageChops.difference(image, bg)
    diff = ImageChops.add(image1=diff, image2=diff, scale=2, offset=-30)
    bbox = diff.getbbox()
    return image.crop(bbox)


def resize_blur(blur_img: Image, sizers: tuple[int, int]) -> Image:
    return (
        blur_img
        .resize(sizers, resample=Resampling.LANCZOS)
        .filter(ImageFilter.GaussianBlur(10))
    )


def resize_width_main(border_img: Image, size_width: int) -> Image:
    width, height = border_img.size[:2]
    w_percent = size_width / width
    h_size = round(height * w_percent)
    return border_img.resize((size_width, h_size), Resampling.LANCZOS)


def center_overlay(overlay_img: Image, blur_img: Image) -> None:
    box = [
        round((xb - xo)/2)
        for xb, xo in zip(blur_img.size, overlay_img.size)
    ][:2]
    blur_img.paste(im=overlay_img, box=box)


def main() -> None:
    image = PIL.Image.open('resized_download.png')
    border_img = remove_border(image)
    blur_img = resize_blur(border_img, (1080, 1080))
    overlay_img = resize_width_main(border_img, 1080)
    center_overlay(overlay_img, blur_img)
    blur_img.save('resized.png')


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Comment: Hi @Reinderien thanks for support, about ```LANCZOS``` when i use this method i get this message: ```DeprecationWarning: LANCZOS is deprecated and will be removed in Pillow 10 (2023-07-01). Use Resampling.LANCZOS instead.
  from PIL.Image import Image, LANCZOS```that's why my code is the way you thought it was different.

Comment: OK, that makes sense. I'm on Pillow 9.0 so that explains the difference.